# Recursive insert binary search tree JAVA

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, computer-science

I have this code and I'm finding difficulties to write it in a recursive way (insert method in Binary search tree)

```
    public void insert(E element){
        BTNode<E> node=root;
        boolean stop=false;
        while(!stop){
            if(element.compareTo(node.getElement())<0){
                if(node.getLeft()==null){
                    node.setLeft(new BTNode<E>(element));
                    stop=true;
                } else{
                    node=node.getLeft();
                }
            }
            else{
                if(node.getRight()==null){
                    node.setRight(new BTNode<E>(element));
                    stop=true;
                } else{
                    node=node.getRight();
                }
            }
                
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a method that accepts the root and the element to be inserted and returns the modified root.

```
public BTNode<E> insert(BTNode<E> root, E element) {
   if ( root == null ) {
      root = new BTNode<E>(element);
   } else if ( element.compareTo(root.getElement()) < 0 ) {
      root.left = insert(root.left, element);
   } else {
      root.right = insert(root.right, element);
   }
   return root;
}
```